# An error occurred when accepting terms of service when register Android app in Firebase App Check

Tags: android, firebase-console, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

When I'm trying to register the Firebase App Check for the Android App, I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

Does anyone face this error in Firebase?
I tried deleting the app and register it once again but it didn't help, logging in from another account, different network, different browser and other basic solutions didn't really helped